# How to fetch related data between these two tables

Tags: mysql

I have got two tables by name **pricechangeimpwl** and **suppourtimpwl**

The two tables contain **name** in common .

This is my schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pricechangeimpwl` (
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time1` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time2` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `whatnext` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `stock_low` decimal(6,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `buy_sell_diff` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `pricechangeimpwl` (`name`, `p1`, `time1`, `p2`, `time2`, `whatnext`, `stock_low`, `buy_sell_diff`) VALUES
    ('DIVISLAB', 631.75, '2017-03-21 15:29:09', 630.85, '2017-03-21 15:40:47', 'plzcontinue', 628.60, '-417055'),
    ('M&M', 1297.00, '2017-03-21 15:29:09', 1299.00, '2017-03-21 15:40:47', 'plzcontinue', 1271.00, '9190');


    -- Dumping structure for table trade_chit_chat.suppourtimpwl
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `suppourtimpwl` (
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `suppourt1` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `suppourt2` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `suppourt3` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;




INSERT INTO `suppourtimpwl` (`name`, `suppourt1`, `suppourt2`, `suppourt3`, `date`) VALUES
    ('DIVISLAB', 762.54, 752.68, 739.35, '20 March 2017'),
    ('M&M', 1292.25, 1284.30, 1273.41, '20 March 2017');
```

This is my sql fiddle 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a9476/1

Can we write a select query so that it will fetch suppourt1 , suppourt2 and suppourt3 values for each symbol of pricechangeimpwl ??

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from pricechangeimpwl p JOIN suppourtimpwl s
on p.name = s.name;
```

Comment: thank you , i was thinning this way SELECT a.name, a.suppourt1, b.p1
     FROM suppourtimpwl a, pricechangeimpwl b
     WHERE a.name = b.name;

Comment: You would get the same result with the same performance. But in my opinion an explicit JOIN is much more readable. But it's your decision ;).